# Angular HTTP Res JSON Data print in html

Tags: json, angular, http

Below is the HTTP get request response. how can i print same in view using *ngFor . iam trying to print single object print like data[0].value1 in console. it returns undefined. inside data array 3 JSON Objects. and some arrays also

Any help much appreciated...

```
getEmp(){
    this.EmpService.getAccounts().subscribe((res : any[])=>{      
      this.products = JSON.stringify(res);
  });
```

.

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "value1": "3546786908765432",
                "category": "Clothing (Brand)",
                "category_list": [
                    {
                        "id": "001",
                        "name": "Clothing (Brand)"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "39324324230",
                        "name": "Boutique Store"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "12342324324",
                        "name": "Website"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "wqeqws",
                "id": "qwsqwsq  w",
                "tasks": [
                    "ANALYZE",
                    "ADVERTISE",
                    "MODERATE",
                    "CREATE_CONTENT",
                    "MANAGE"
                ]
            },
            {
                "value1": "111-9=-09876543",
                "category": "Education",
                "category_list": [
                    {
                        "id": "23456",
                        "name": "Education"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "sdcsfcsdfvsd",
                "id": "111111111111",
                "tasks": [
                    "ANALYZE",
                    "ADVERTISE",
                    "MODERATE",
                    "CREATE_CONTENT",
                    "MANAGE"
                ]
            }
    ],
        "paging": {
            "cursors": {
                "before": "dsfsds",
                "after": "sdfsfs"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you assigning the response to a variable? Please show that.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.products = res.data;
```

In your page

```
< *ngFor="let item of products >
```